# Не получается посчитать количество записей в Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Учу php. Пишу форум. Не получается у меня посчитать корректно записи в  базе данных. Подставляется почему то последнее значение массива. Помогите решить проблему? Запрос $query888 отвечает за подсчет всех сообщений. Нужно посчитать сколько всего сообщений было оставлено в каждой секции. На фото массив $data888. Там все корректно, но вот почему то подставляется только последнее значение для всх элементов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM section LEFT JOIN chapter ON section.id_chapter = chapter.id_chapter";
 $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error($link));
 for ($data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row);

 $content = '';

 $query777 = "SELECT section_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM themes GROUP BY section_id";
 $result777 = mysqli_query($link, $query777) or die (mysqli_error($link));
 for ($data777 = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result777); $data777[] = $row);

 $query888 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM answers GROUP BY section";
 $result888 = mysqli_query($link, $query888) or die (mysqli_error($link));
 for ($data888 = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result888); $data888[] = $row);
 var_dump($data888);

 foreach ($data as $elem) {
     foreach ($data888 as $elem888) {
         $count1 = $elem888['count'];
     }
     foreach ($data777 as $elem777) {
            if ($elem777['section_id'] == $elem['id_section']) {
                $count = $elem777['count'];
            }
        }
        $content .= "<li class=\"rows_item\">";
            $content .= "<div class=\"rows_main_item_wrap\">";
            $content .=  "<div class=\"rows_main_item_left\">
                                <a href=\"?item=$elem[id_section]\">$elem[name_section]</a>
                           </div>";
            $content .=     "<div class=\"rows_main_item_top\">
                                    <p><span>Тем: $count</span></p>
                                    <p><span>Сообщений: $count1</span></p>
                            </div>";
            $content .=     "<div class=\"rows_main_item_right\">
                                    <p> помогите пожалуйста выташить... </p>
                                    <p> от paraiso </p>
                                    <p> 19.03.2019, 21:15 </p>
                            </div>";
            $content .= "</div>";

        $content .= "</li>";
    }
```

Comment: В цикле `foreach ($data888 as $elem888) {$count1 = $elem888['count'];}` в каждой итерации переписывается одна и та же переменная. Поэтому всегда в `$count1` будет последнее значение

Comment: Да это то я понял. Мне бы понять как сделать правильно. Я только учу php. Голова закипает быстро.

Comment: причина проста. Из всех возможых источников для изучения РНР вы выбрали тот, который был создан очередным жадным дураком  на материале прошлого века.

Comment: Тут я спорить не буду. Так оно и есть. Может быть посоветуете что то более стоящее? ООП я просто еще не проходил. оно дальше будет. Пока практикуюсь из того, что имею.

Comment: дело не в ооп. дело в том что вы же все равно не воспринимаете печатные руководства, а любой видеоматериал будет преподавать такой же ад. И в итоге из вас получится не программист, а кустарь, который только и умеет на коленке написать пару строк кода.

Comment: и судя по картинке, ты потом будешь этому же самом похапе учить других. если уже не начал

Comment: @Ипатьев ну что вы так) Стремление к познанию само по себе похвально, а на истинный путь всегда можно направить, посоветовав проверенный материал. Не похоже, что Roman собирается сопротивляться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Старайтесь получить из базы данных все данные за один запрос, это возможно практически в любой ситуации. Действия которые вы делаете в php, MySQL может выполнить самостоятельно и скорее всего это будет быстрее.

```
SELECT section.*, chapter.*, themes_count, section_count
  FROM section
  LEFT JOIN chapter ON section.id_chapter = chapter.id_chapter
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT section_id, COUNT(*) as themes_count
        FROM themes GROUP BY section_id
  ) th ON th.section_id = section.section_id
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT section, COUNT(*) as section_count
        FROM answers GROUP BY section
  ) sec ON sec.section = section.section_id
```

Данный запрос вернет все необходимые вам данные, уже собранные по секциям, на php останется только вывести их на экран. И стоит заменить `*` в запросе на те колонки данных, которые реально нужны на выводе.

Comment: Несомненно, это лучше чем вводить постоянно новые запросы. Но я пока только учусь. И связывание таблиц мне тяжело дается. Да и продумать толком какие таблицы и поля нужны я еще не могу, поэтому постоянно новые поля добавляю в ходе реализации. А за совет большое спасибо, обязательно воспользуюсь. Хоть и первый раз слышу, что так можно делать, я думал каждый раз новый запрос нужно делать))

Answer (score 2):

Если изменить запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM answers GROUP BY section
```

на

```
SELECT section, COUNT(*) as count FROM answers GROUP BY section
```

В каждой строке выборки у вас будет не только количество записей, но и ID раздела, к которому они относятся. Так вы сможете правильно ассоциировать данные

Comment: Спасибо большое. Получилось. Добавил условие и норм))